Site Indexed but Not Ranking for Unique Keywords—Any Insights?
If I search site:example.com in Google and I get results, does that guarantee that my site is indexed by Google?
I'm asking because that search yields perfect results, but when I search using really unique keywords that would only appear on my site (without the site: argument) I don't show up at all. My site is kind of new (7 months old) and pretty simple, but I feel like a search unique to my site should show up as a top result.
Everything looks good in google search console too. Sitemap submitted, 8 pages discovered, home page canonical declared, all pages say crawled and indexed. But how come it's impossible to rank in any searches?

Lots of people are seeing content not appear at the moment, and I assume it is to do with their fighting AI - see https://www.vincentschmalbach.com/google-now-defaults-to-not-indexing-your-content/ for one take. I've personally had pages where some, but not all, of the content appears in search. I suspect getting decent backlinks to individual pages may improve your chance of it ranking for non site: searches, but that's a guess not an answer.

site: is a special case. It does mean Google is aware of it, but is no guarantee it will show up in search results. e.g. Google may prefer another page on a different website over a result in a site: search, but because of the site: restriction it will be shown.
